# Write a MAIN function and two FUNCTIONS to compute and print the elements of a two-dimensional 30X25 integer array A which are square numbers

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, parameters

When I set the cols=25 and I set the value of rows more than 25 , I run the program but ıt cant show the descending array and the array without duplicates. It just show the array you get from the first function and it cant show the enough elements of array. Example

(B: 81 9 16 64 1 64 49 9 1 100 25 4 16)

And I set the value of the row as less than 25 ,the program works. I think I should open place for pointer B that more size than the array I get from function1. I think I should use dynamic memory allocation for this problem.
The result I want to get this is

(B: 4 36 4 36 16 49 16 25 81 25 81 9 16 81 9 16 81 4 1 81 64 64 81 16 49 81 64 4 9 25 4 4 4 49 81 64 81 1 81 64 1 100 49 64 36 25 81 25 36 81 1 64 4 4 64 9 36 16 49 81 9 25 81 16 1 64 9 25 100

There are 69 squared numbers in that array

Descending sorted array is: 100 100 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 49 49 49 49 49 36 36 36 36 36 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 9 9 9 9 9 9 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1

Arrays without duplicates: 100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1)

And I dont understand pointers completely.I guess I can run this program without wrong,ıf ı use the pointers in all functions.But I want to use pointers as little as possible.  Pls help me

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>

int cols=25;
int rows=25;
int function1(int A[][cols],int size,int *B);
int function2(int *B,int size);

int main(){
    int i,j;
  int A[rows][cols];
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (i=0;i<rows;i++){
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
      A[i][j] = 1+(rand()%100);
    }
    }
   /*for (i=0;i<rows;i++){ 
     printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
      printf("%d  ",A[i][j]);
    } 
  }*/
  printf("\n");
  int *B;
  int size=function1(A,rows,B);
  printf("\n");
  function2(B,size);
  
  return 0;
}

int function1(int A[][cols],int size,int *B){  
  int i,j,k=0;
  printf("B: ");
     for(i=0;i<size;i++){
       for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
        for(int m=1;m<=10;m++){
          if(A[i][j]==m*m){
            B[k]=A[i][j];
            printf("%d ",B[k]);
            k++;
          }
        }    
         }
     }
  printf("\n");
  printf("There are %d squared numbers in that array",k);
  return k;
}

int function2(int *B,int size) {
  int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<size;i++){
   for(j=i+1;j<size;j++){
     if(B[j]>B[i]){
      int gecici=B[j];
      B[j]=B[i];
      B[i]=gecici;
    }
     }
 }
  printf("Descending sorted array is: ");
  for(int k=0;k<size;k++){
    printf("%d ",B[k]);    
  }
  printf("\n");
    int m,l,k;
    for(m=0;m<size;m++){
        for(l=m+1;l<size;l++){
            if(B[l]==B[m]){
                for(k=l;k<size-1;k++){
                    B[k]=B[k+1];
                }
                size--;
                l--; 
            } 
        }
    }
    printf("Arrays without duplicates: ");
    for(int a=0;a<size;a++){
        printf("%d ",B[a]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what the actual problem/error is? That is, what happens when it doesn't work. Also, please fix up your code formatting so that it is more readable. In particular, fix up the indentation to make it consistent.

Comment: `B` is an uninitialized pointer. You need to point it at something. Better yet, just do something like `int B[rows * cols];`

Comment: `function2()` does too many different things — it sorts the data and prints it twice.  That should probably be three separate functions.

Comment: @kaylum When I set the cols=25 and   I set the value of rows more than 25 , I run the program but ıt cant show the descending array and the array without duplicates. It just show the array you get from the first function and it cant show the enough elements of array. Example

Comment: B: 81 9 16 64 1 64 49 9 1 100 25 4 16

Comment: And I set the value of the row as less than 25 ,the program works. I think I should open place for pointer B that more size than the array I get from function1. I  think I should use   dynamic memory allocation for this problem. What do you think

Comment: The result I want to get this is

Comment: B: 4 36 4 36 16 49 16 25 81 25 81 9 16 81 9 16 81 4 1 81 64 64 81 16 49 81 64 4 9 25 4 4 4 49 81 64 81 1 81 64 1 100 49 64 36 25 81 25 36 81 1 64 4 
4 64 9 36 16 49 81 9 25 81 16 1 64 9 25 100
There are 69 squared numbers in that array
Descending sorted array is: 100 100 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 49 49 49 49 49 36 36 36 36 36 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 9 9 9 9 9 9 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1
Arrays without duplicates: 100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74366810/edit) the post to update it with that important info. Not in comments where it can't be formatted properly and is easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

In this code `B` is an uninitialized pointer. When it is dereferenced and written to inside `function1` you have undefined behavior. This is always a bug but it may have worked for you with a smaller data set just because it didn't happen to overwrite anything important enough to cause a crash.

```
int *B;
int size=function1(A,rows,B);
```

A simple fix is to use an array instead of a pointer.

```
int B[rows * cols];
int size=function1(A,rows,B);
```

With this fix the program generates the correct output:

```
B: 100 100 4 9 4 1 100 25 64 1 1 1 9 9 1 16 64 100 100 49 9 49 81 4 64 81 81 64 25 64 49 64 100 4 16 1 9 1 36 9 36 1 81 49 16 16 64 1 4 36 36 4 100 81 4 16 49 100 49 16 9 1 100 9 64 81 1 1 4 81 1 
There are 71 squared numbers in that array
Descending sorted array is: 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 49 49 49 49 49 49 36 36 36 36 25 25 16 16 16 16 16 16 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
Arrays without duplicates: 100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d47vYjTe3)